# What is the Difference OpenCV Face Detection from an image and from a Camera?

Tags: opencv, video-capture, face-detection, face-recognition

i write a OpenCV document over the Face Detection from a Video and Face Recognation using eigenface from a video.

I have finding in internet many of documantations over face detection from a image. And Face Recognition using eigenfaces from a image.

My question is:

If i detect or recognize faces from camera: the camera take a photo and save this in "vectors" or in a xml file? LIKE detect face and recognize face from a image?

best regards Adrianos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenCV, when you try to do a face-recognition, the existing algorithms work with an input array, representing the image. So you hve to work with an image.

Plus, there are different ways to get a stream from a camera (like VideoCapture, or cvCaptureFromCAM depending on the language), but the only thing you can do with theses is to "take a snapshot", save this image in a matrix, and treat the image.

So yeah, there's no difference between face detection in an image and face detection from a camera